# Different editing tools in Windows 10 Photos app

Tags: windows-10, photos

I have Windows 10 on two different computers and recently noticed that the editing tools in the Photos app are different on each.

On one computer I have the newer version with a bunch of filters and slider-based editing tools:

[image]

Whereas the other has the older version with circular editing tools and buttons on each side of the image:

[image]

Both are running the same OS build (14393.726) and app version (16.1118.10000.0) and are fully up-to-date. Is there something that determines which editing tools are used? And how can I get the same version on both (ideally the older version)?

Comment: Both machines are on the Release Preview branch. Although I think the new editing tools and UI changes were rolled out to everyone a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

> Both are running the same OS build (14393.726) and app version
>   (16.1118.10000.0) and are fully up-to-date. Is there something that
>   determines which editing tools are used? And how can I get the same
>   version on both (ideally the older version)?

Based on the article: [New features arrive in Microsoft Photos on Windows 10](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/12/13/new-features-arrive-microsoft-photos-windows-10/#i4MJvzdyZ3Tu4bxF.97)

It appears while the new interface for Microsoft Photos is completed it still is being slowly pushed out to users.  I base my conclusion, based on the fact they are still collecting feedback, as stated in the following statement by Microsoft

> We’re making a big investment in Photos these days and we want your
>   feedback on how to make it better. You are a key part of all the
>   changes we make to the Photos experience. Try out the latest update,
>   edit some photos, draw on some videos, and continue to share your
>   feedback with us through the built-in feedback tool. You can find
>   “Send Feedback” under the “…” menu.

*It is worth pointing out the article was lasted updated on January 19, 2017 2:43 pm.*

So the simplest solution is to just uninstall and reinstall it.  I have confirmed when you do this, the notification that explains the look has changed, appears again.

It appears that, in order to have the ability to uninstall the Photos application, you have to use [StartIsBack](http://www.startisback.com/).  Once you have it installed, you can uninstall the Photo application, by selecting uninstall.  Once you have it uninstalled you can uninstall StartIsBack.

[image]

You can initiate the installation process, by going to the [Microsoft Photos](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/microsoft-photos/9wzdncrfjbh4), application page.  You can also locate it in the Store and simply install it.

[image]

[image]

Once the application is installed and you launch, the following notification, should be displayed.

[image]

Comment: I didn't see anything in that article to suggest the new UI shouldn't be available to everyone. Maybe some sort of bug is keeping one of my PCs on the old UI? In any case, I would actually like to keep the old UI as it's much better suited to actually editing pictures (as opposed to playing with filters). I don't suppose there's any way to get it on the other PC as well? Maybe copying over the app files or something?

Comment: No;  Your suggest course of action won't work.  *You have to read between what Microsoft actually said and what they didn't say to conclude that they were slowing pushing out the changes.*